# bind textblock to current listbox item in pure xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

i have some data saved in a xml file.
Those will be displayed in a listbox.
Now, when i change the listbox Selectedindex, i would like to update the other information in the textblock based on the selectedindex.

is there any way to do this in pure xaml?
if not, how would i bind the Textblock to the selecteditem in the listbox ?

**EDIT:
How would i navigate through the Data without using the listbox? i mean using a button to move to next item and other button to move backward..!!**

any help is really appreciated..

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSingleInstance.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Background="Cornsilk">

        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="InventoryData" XPath="Inventory/Books">
                <x:XData>
                    <Inventory xmlns="">
                        <Books>
                            <Book ISBN="0-7356-0562-9" Stock="in" Number="9">
                                <Title>XML in Action</Title>
                                <Summary>XML Web Technology</Summary>
                            </Book>
                            <Book ISBN="0-7356-1370-2" Stock="in" Number="8">
                                <Title>Programming Microsoft Windows With C#</Title>
                                <Summary>C# Programming using the .NET Framework</Summary>
                            </Book>
                            <Book ISBN="0-7356-1288-9" Stock="out" Number="7">
                                <Title>Inside C#</Title>
                                <Summary>C# Language Programming</Summary>
                            </Book>
                        </Books>
                    </Inventory>
                </x:XData>
            </XmlDataProvider>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10"
HorizontalAlignment="Center">XML Data Source Sample</TextBlock>
        <ListBox
Width="265" Height="98" x:Name="lbox" Background="Honeydew" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource InventoryData}"
           XPath="*[@Stock='out'] | *[@Number>=8 or @Number=3]"/>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Foreground="Red">
      <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding XPath="Title"/>
      </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource InventoryData}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding  XPath=Book/Title}"/>
            <TextBox Margin="5,31,98,10" x:Name="textBoxMainDetail" Text="{Binding XPath=Book/Summary}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>



</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=lbox, Path=SelectedItem[Title].InnerText}" />
```

SelectedItem is an [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx).

**EDIT:** Here is a bit of sample code how to access the data of the XmlDataProvider in code behind and apply it as DataContent of a TextBox.

Change the TextBox.Text binding like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxMainDetail" Text="{Binding Path=[Title].InnerText}" />
```

In code behind get the XML data from the XmlDataProvider and set the DataContext of the TextBox:

```
XmlDataProvider dataProvider = (XmlDataProvider)stackPanel.Resources["InventoryData"];
XmlElement books = (XmlElement)dataProvider.Document.SelectNodes(dataProvider.XPath)[0];

// set DataContext to an item from the child node collection
textBoxMainDetail.DataContext = books.ChildNodes[0];
```

Note that the StackPanel with the XmlDataProvider in its resource dictionary has now got a name. If this code shall run during application initialization (e.g. in Window constructor), the `XmlDataProvider.IsAsynchronous` property must be set to false.

You should now be able to change the DataContext to another indexed item of the books collection in a button click handler.

Comment: Hi, thanks that works... can i also add a button to navigate through the data without using the listbox? i mean if i delete the listbox, how would i navigate through the xml data ?moveforward(), moveback() and so on..

Comment: I guess that navigating through the data without the ListBox might better by done in code behind. Something ought to keep track of a current/selected item.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `SelectedValuePath` as the 'Title' for your listbox. Then simply bind the your textBlock to the selectedValue of your listbox using elementName like this -

```
<ListBox Width="265" Height="98" x:Name="lbox" Background="Honeydew"
                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedValuePath="Title">
            </ListBox>
            <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource InventoryData}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=lbox}"/>
                <TextBox Margin="5,31,98,10" x:Name="textBoxMainDetail" Text="{Binding XPath=Book/Summary}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```