# Data binding access in xaml vs in code behind - Linq to XML?

Tags: wpf, xml, linq, data-binding, listbox

I have a listbox that binds to and displays the Name elements from an XML file. When a listbox item is selected, I want to display the Price value associated with this item in a textblock. How do I retrieve the Price programmatically (meaning not in the xaml file but in code behind)? Thanks.

XML file has these nodes:

```
<Product>
    <Name>Book</Name>
    <Price>7</Price>
</Product>
```

I use Linq and do the `select` with an **anonymous type**. If the easiest way to access the field programmatically is through a named type, please show me how.

Here's how I bind in xaml (using a data template for each listbox item that contains):

```
 <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Name}" />
```

Here's the code-behind function where I want to retrieve the Price:

```
        private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
       // how do I get the value of Price of the selected item here?
    }
```

**Please note that I want to access Price in this function, NOT in xaml!**

Comment: That depends on how you are binding. Do you go via an XMLDataProvider or manually retrieve the XMLNodes? Can you show your code?

Comment: @SvenG I've just added the binding for Name which is done in xaml. I use Linq to read the xml file so I don't directly use any XMLDataProvider.

Comment: Can you please show the ViewModel and the XAML around that TextBlock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you probably don't even need LINQ as you can do a lot of things with `XmlDocuments` including doing selection via XPath ([also in Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx)).

Secondly converting anonymous types to named types is trivial, if you have

```cs
select new { Name = ..., Price = ... }
```

You just need a class with the respective properties

```cs
select new Product { Name = ..., Price = ... }
```

```cs
public class Product
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Price { get; set; } // Datatype is up to you...
}
```

Thirdly you can make do without named types using [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx).

```cs
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
   var listBox = (ListBox)sender;
   // Named type:
   Product item = (Product)listBox.SelectedItem;
   // Anonymous type:
   dynamic item = listBox.SelectedItem;
   // <Do something with item.Price, may need to cast it when using dynamic>
   // e.g. MessageBox.Show((string)item.Price);
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely brilliant. Thanks so much! I need to wait 15 hours before I am allowed to click "award bounty" though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the selected item from the SelectionChangedEventArgs parameter. i.e.

```
var item = e.AddedItems.First();
```

Comment: I want to retrieve the Price element associated with the selected item. Not the selected item.

Comment: @user776676: So you cannot get an child XML node from an element or what?

Comment: I've just added info to the question re what I want to do. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this post - [bind textblock to current listbox item in pure xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112083/bind-textblock-to-current-listbox-item-in-pure-xaml/9112661#9112661), you can get the name both in xaml and code-behind using `XmlDataProvider`.

Comment: That code only use xaml as far as I could see. I want to access Price in code behind so I can do some calculation with it.