# avoid anonymous types in datacontext?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml, datagrid

I have this datagrid

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Name="DataGrid6S" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="50" Binding="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Collapsed"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Text}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Click="Button_Click" >View Details</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

which is populated by the following code:

```
class Test {
        public int W { get; set; }
        public string X { get; set; }
        public string Y { get; set; }
    }

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
        testList.Add(new Test() { W = 0, X = "hello", Y = "one" });
        testList.Add(new Test() { W = 1, X = "hello", Y = "two" });
        testList.Add(new Test() { W = 2, X = "hello", Y = "three" });
        testList.Add(new Test() { W = 3, X = "hello", Y = "four" });

        var query =
            from values in testList
            select new { ID = values.W, Name = values.X, Text = values.Y };

        DataGrid6S.ItemsSource = query;

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var obj = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
        // Can't access values because it's of an anoymous type.
        // What do I have to do to be able to access the values stored here?

    }
}
```

When a button is clicked, I'd like to know the ID of the row on which that button was clicked, but I can't find out because the rows are initialized with anonymous types, what do I have to do to find out the ID of the clicked row?

note: This is a simplified version assume that query consists of 5 joins & a where clause.

Comment: One does not use an as-cast like that, i would recommend. `var button = (FrameworkElement)sender; var context = (Bla)button.DataContext;` Only use as-casts if you check for null afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a named type and select instances of that, anonymous types are for objects that are only edited within the scope in which they are created. Also why not use the `Test` class directly? The only difference are property names. Also do not forget to cast the `DataContext` to your named type as it is an `object`.

Comment: How? I don't know the full C# syntax yet, and I've tried to search an answer for this question, it's just that nobody is as dumb as me ;_;

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164381/546730). Also if you have trouble casting: You already did a cast to `FrameworkElement`, works the same way for any other class.

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork: Don't edit your question, answers **do not** belong there. If anything post an answer. (Also i do not think the implementation details are necessary)

Comment: can't do that, apparently I don't have enough reputation yet. w/e. I'll post it tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use an anonymous type in the query?  You already have a nice object that can hold all of the data you need, in exactly the format you have it in.  You explicitly remove all of that helpful information by converting it into an anonymous query.  Just set `testList` as the data source and access the `Test` item in the button click.